# Change divs associated to links on hover

Tags: javascript, hover, hyperlink

I have a list of links on one side and given a div outside of that list, I'd like to change the content of that div by hovering on the links so that for each link I can display a correspondent div with some info inside.

An example of what I'd like to achieve is on this page:

http://www.darley.co.uk/stallions/our-stallions

As you can see, if you hover on a horse's name on the list, the div on the right changes to display the info relative to that horse.

I have checked the code of that page but I can't see any Javascript associated with this effect and there's nothing on the HTML code either.

Any idea on how I can replicate that effect?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi there! I've found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396159/using-jquery-how-to-change-an-image-when-hovering-links but I'm not sure how to implement the code, I'm not very familiar with Javascript to be honest...

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `data-id` attributes on the element that you hover over and have a bunch of div's with the contents for the corresponding content that you wish to display.  On the div add the matching id that you put in the value for the `data-id` attribute on the link.  Have all but the first div hidden by default and do something like.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#sidebar a').hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.data('id');
    $('.genericdivclass').slideUp(250); //Hide the visible divs
    $('#' + id).slideDown(250);
  });
});
```

Just be sure you replace the dummy attributes I used with ones that match your markup.

Comment: Hi @CWitty I tried your code and it's very close to what I want to achieve but I still have some issues, for instance how do I hide all but the first div? At the moment when I open the page all the divs are visible...

Comment: You can add a class of hidden to the elements and add a CSS rule to set them to `display:none;` or using jQuery you can do `$('.hidden').hide(0);`

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I've implemented your code and changed it to suit my need... I really appreciate it!

Comment: If you wouldnt mind accepting this as the answer if it works, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

From http://api.jquery.com/hover/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>hover demo</title>
  <style>
  ul {
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: blue;
  }
  li {
    cursor: default;
  }
  span {
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Bread</li>
  <li class="fade">Chips</li>
  <li class="fade">Socks</li>
</ul>

<script>
$( "li" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<span> ***</span>" ) );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
  }
);

$( "li.fade" ).hover(function() {
  $( this ).fadeOut( 100 );
  $( this ).fadeIn( 500 );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following Link

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#mouseover

hope this helps

Comment: Hi @Sid M I will definitely try the jquery tab... that could be the solution to my problem thanks for your answer!

Comment: I tried the jQuery tab but I need to hover over the links, not click on them! Thanks anyway!

Comment: you can get mouse hover option in examples of jquery tabs,see that example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
 <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"      type="text/javascript"></script> 
 </head>
 <body>
<style>
   .horse{ display:none; }   
</style>
<script>
      $(function() {
         $(".links").mouseover( function() {
         $(".horse").hide();
         $("#horse_info_"+$(this).attr('id')).show();
     });    
  });
</script>
<div>
   <div style="width: 200px;float:left">    
    <br><a class="links" id="1" href="/">link1</a>  
    <br><a class="links" id="2" href="/">link2</a>  
    <br><a class="links" id="3" href="/">link3</a>  
    <br><a class="links" id="4" href="/">link4</a>  
    <br><a class="links" id="5" href="/">link5</a>  
    <br><a class="links" id="6" href="/">link6</a>  
   </div>

   <div style="width: 200px;float:left">    
    <div class="horse" id="horse_info_1">
       info about horse 1                 
    </div>

    <div class="horse" id="horse_info_2">
       info about horse 2                 
    </div>

    <div class="horse" id="horse_info_3">
       info about horse 3                 
    </div>

    <div class="horse" id="horse_info_4">
       info about horse 4                 
    </div>

    <div class="horse" id="horse_info_5">
       info about horse 5                 
    </div>

    <div class="horse" id="horse_info_6">
       info about horse 6                 
    </div>

   </div>   
</div>
```